# What Can I be Researching to speed this python scripted mysql-query up?

Tags: python, mysql, performance

so I spent a long time on the site yesterday to write this entire script in python (which I had never before used). I was pleased with the results (it worked on my tiny test-data set of 10,000 entries), but now that I'm using production data (many million) it is incredibly slow.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import MySQLdb
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is used to actually generate matched lists. outputs those that matched")
parser.add_argument("Database", help="The name of the database you want to run matching against")
args = parser.parse_args()


tablename = str(sys.argv[1])
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='[REDACTED]',
    db='Data')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE md5 IN (select md5 from %s)" %tablename
cursor.execute(sql)

data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data :
    print row[0]
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

to explain how my tables look:

table1 | name | md5

table2 | md5

I'm sure there's some optimization I could do on the server itself to make mysql faster, but my suspicion is that there's some ways I could have made this faster in the code itself. Any suggestions on where to continue researching this would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name 
FROM
 table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON
   t2.md5 = t1.md5
```

And you should also **index the md5 columns** on both tables!

The *in* operator acts much like a *left outer join*, so you are giving the server an enormous amount of data to process when you only want the names of the md5 columns that match!

Comment: yes! I forgot all about INNER JOIN. my question for you real quick is: what is t1.name? is it something I'm defining?

Comment: t1 is an alias, since you have tables with the same column names. Its the same has writing table1.name

Comment: As a bonus: replace `data = cursor.fetchall(); for row in data` with `for row in cursor` - this will avoid filling up your memory for nothing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: thanks! I did that and it worked great! to answer your security issue above: the data I'm passing definitely isn't raw user inputs, it's scrubbed and sanitized BEFORE this process. Though, if you have a suggestion on how to do it here, I'd appreciate that!